# Excel VBA data reactid

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to extract data from a website but most of the data is hidden unless LOAD ALL EVENTS is clicked. Inspected the load all events link and it is a data reactid link. Any idea how to expand the table using Excel VBA? The link website is https://online.singaporepools.com/sportsbook/en/home. Thank you.This is what I have tried so far but only displayed data is captured.

```
Sub DataMining()

Dim ie As Object

   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
   Range("A2:AZ3000").Clear


   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://online.singaporepools.com/sportsbook/en/home"

     Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop


       ie.document.getElementsByclassname ("table-condensed")

        x = .document.body.innertext
        x = Replace(x, Chr(10), Chr(13))
        x = Split(x, Chr(13))
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

        Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(x)) = Application.Transpose(x)



     .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a87ef.jpg)

Comment: Cant see the link you have provided. Also, as we are not a code writing service, please provide the code you have tried so far and we should be able to help

Comment: Hi Zac. Thanks for looking. Had updated the VBA code.

Comment: Unfortunately the website is only visible in Singapore which makes it a bit difficult for me. Hopefully someone from Singapore can help with this

Comment: Hi Zac. Thanks for trying. Had put another snapshot of the code shown using Inspect.

Comment: please indent your code by 4 or more spaces so that all of it shows up as code